# Insert data into database table from csv file where csv file headers and table attributes are matched

Tags: sql

I have to insert data from a `.csv` file into a database table.

For example, the table has 20 columns and the `.csv` file has 10 columns, then data has to be inserted where file headers and table columns match.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Note that this is a Q&A site and not a code writing service. So please show us what you already tried and where you got stuck. See also [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, it would be good to specify the database system you use.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Importing a CSV file is typically a feature of the SQL client application (the program where you run the SQL statements). So we also need to know the SQL client you are using.